# Java Socket closes after 5 mins altough it is active

Tags: java, android, sockets

I have a active connection and I am sending and receiving data between client and server. The server is an OBD2 Wifi Dongle.

Everything is working fine but the socket closed exactly after 5 minutes. There is no inactivity. I am constantly communicating with the server.

Do you have any ideas? Or does it seems that OBD Dongle is closing the connection? Because it always ecaxtly after 5 minutes

Comment: in socket programming concept there's something called heartbeat, and timeout to keep connection for exact mention time, in heartbeat feature you can send data to your client from server to keep connection alive and .... so if you need more information or i didn't provide you useful information let me know more info on your issue to help you out

Comment: I know but I have an active communication, so I think a heartbeat is not need. And the Timout is just establishing the connection right? Or is there also Timeout when the connection is going to be closed?

Comment: Server will connect to a socket, and wait to accept a client connection
I think you would be able to solve your problem simply by having the client spawn a heartbeat thread that sleeps for the duration of the heartbeat, then wakes up to send a heartbeat ping to the server. The heartbeat thread on the client would live as long as the client does, it would just loop

Answer (score 0):

Just send a heartbeat, e.g. every 5 seconds a `3E` – this means 'TESTER PRESENT', keeps the socket alive, and is actually a requirement for some vehicle protocols anyways.